# Import Mongo database from snapshot volume AWS

Tags: mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ebs

I have 2 mongo cluster with 3 nodes and a replica set configurated. The goal is to import the database from **clusterA** to **clusterB** via a master snapshot.

Those are the steps that I followed.

- Created snapshot from Ec2 **masterA**.
- Created **volumeA** from created snapshot.
- Attach **volumeA** to **masterB**.
- Mounted **volumeA** in **masterB** in **/data/db2**.
- Updated **/etc/mongo/mongod.conf** to point the new storage.
- Restarted MongoDB.

No errors when restarting, but when I connect back to the database, I still see the old collections. However, the directory **/data/db2** shows a different size and matches the database in **clusterA**.

Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

So, we have one mongo cluster clusterA, with 1 master and 2 workers.

In clusterA, we make a snapshot from master volume, snapA and we create a volume from that snapshot volumeA.

If we want to import mongo database from clusterA to clusterB:

- First, attach volumeA in masterB.
- Mount volume, for example in /data/db2.

Once the volume is attached and mounted, follow this Mongo guide https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/restore-replica-set-from-backup/.

After that, you'll have successfully imported a mongo backup from clusterA to clusterB via volume snapshot.

Regards.